# Discouraging test problem

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms, problem-solving

This is by far one of the most exaggerated problems I've seen. I saw it in a ReactionTime video(of all places) and I decided to attempt it. I have a few solutions where stuff gets equated to 0 but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Here it is: Solve for x in

$\displaystyle\dfrac{6(3x^2-27) \cdot 8x^2}{4(9-3x)(x^2+3x)}=\dfrac{\tan(x+4)}{\log_{10}(x+\frac{1}{4})}$

It's not looking good but at least some intense factorization is possible.

$\displaystyle\dfrac{6\cdot3(x+3)(x-3) \cdot 8x^2}{-4\cdot3(x-3)\cdot x(x+3)}=\dfrac{\tan(x+4)}{\log_{10}(x+\frac{1}{4})}$

$\displaystyle 144x^2(x+3)(x-3) \cdot \log_{10}(x+\frac{1}{4})=-12x(x+3)(x-3) \cdot \tan(x+4)$

$\displaystyle 144x^2(x+3)(x-3) \cdot \log_{10}(x+\frac{1}{4})+12x(x+3)(x-3) \cdot \tan(x+4)=0$

$\displaystyle 12x(x+3)(x-3)(12x \cdot \log_{10}(x+\frac{1}{4})+\tan(x+4))=0$

So my actual question was: how do you solve

$12x \cdot \log_{10}(x+\frac{1}{4})+\tan(x+4)=0$

Please help!

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a closed-form solution? [Transcendental equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) generally do not.

Comment: I just thought there would be hope somewhere, probably even in the complex plane. Newton's method it is then